# How to avoid google line chart annotation text cover each other?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-visualization, google-chat

I create a horizontal line chart with annotation,but annotation text will cover each other when two point too close,how can I avoid annotation cover each other??
here is my sample chart:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLogScales);
function drawLogScales() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'style'});
    data.addRows([
        [0, 0,'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis',''],
        [0, 0,'QAQ',''],    
        [0.1, 0,'ABCDEFG',''],  
        [1, 0,'123',''],     
    ]);
    var options = {};
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

thank you

Comment: Show annotation text in tooltip

Comment: @priya_singh thanks,but I need text shows directly,is it possible to set the annotations.datum.stem.length for each point?

Comment: you can only change the stem length for an entire series / data table column. only option would be to adjust manually on the chart's ready event, by changing the `"y"` attribute on the `<text>` element...

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks,I got the point!

Comment: cheers! nice solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for @WhiteHat advice, finally i found i can create an empty series and shows the annotations:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLogScales);
function drawLogScales() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Z');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
    data.addRows([
        [0, 0,'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis',0,null],
        [0, 0,null,0,'QAQ'],    
        [0.1,0,null,0,'ABCDEFG'],  
        [1, 0,'123',0,null],     
    ]);
    var options = {series: {1: {color: '#3366CC',annotations: {stem: {color: '#3366CC',length :30,},},lineWidth: 0,pointSize: 0,},},};
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```